# LINQ, Group by property while keeping other property sort together

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, grouping

So I am not entirely sure how to explain what it is I am trying to do here. I am attempting to take some data (represented by the Excel file screenshot below), and basically sort by Connection2, while keeping similar items in Connection1 together. (Explained a bit in screen shot below)

**Here is what I have as of right now:**

```cs
var wires = RedConductorWires
    .OrderBy(x => x.Label)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Connection1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Connection2)
    .ToList();
```

**Class Object being sorted(Matches Excel Screenshot):**

```cs
public class CustomExcelFormat
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string WireSize { get; set; }
    public string WireColor { get; set; }
    public string WirePartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Connection1 { get; set; }
    public string Connection1Torque { get; set; }
    public string Connection1Termination { get; set; }
    public string Connection1StripLength { get; set; }
    public string Checkbox1 { get; set; }
    public string Connection2 { get; set; }
    public string Connection2Torque { get; set; }
    public string Connection2Termination { get; set; }
    public string Connection2StripLength { get; set; }
    public string Checkbox2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Screen Shot:**
[image]

**THE PROBLEM:**

The issue is if you look at the screen shot the brown "A1:TB7:M1" cells need to be grouped together as well, and the Green "K7:10" need to be grouped together while maintaining their Connection2 sort/group.

In other words, the connection 2 side of those, K8:10 and K8:11 need to stay grouped together.

So obviously my LINQ query is not correct, I believe I need to do some sort of grouping and then sorting but am unsure how to approach it or even ask this question exactly (If someone could put it into words for me). I basically need to group by items in connection 2, while still keeping connection 1 sorted and together.

If someone could point me in the direction of the LINQ expression that could do something like this that would be great!

**EDIT**

So I used the following query:

```
var wires = RedConductorWires
            .OrderBy(x => x.Label)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Connection2, x.Connection1 })
            .Select(grp => grp.ToList()).SelectMany(i => i).ToList();
```

and got the grouping correct. Now I just need to get it to sort in some alphabetical manner. See picture below.

[image]

Comment: The LINQ appears correct and trying it out for myself the consecutive `ThenBy` calls work as expected. Are you sure you're writing the data to the excel correctly or aren't otherwise tripping over your properties (e.g. using `Connection2` in a place where you meant to use `Connection1` or the like)

Comment: I have also taken the example, and tried to reproduce with an in memory collection based on your example class, and agree that the LINQ query works as expected (sorting by label, then connection1, then connection 2).
How are you reading & writing the data from the spreadsheet?

Comment: @ahillier88 Yes the LINQ query i linked produces the output shown in the picture. That is the problem. Basically if you look at Connection 2 column, items K8:10, the brown/green properties need to be together as well. I am fairly certain I need to do something like group by connection 2 and 1, then order by Connection 1 or something along those lines?

Comment: The table is result of `.OrderBy(x => x.Label).ThenBy(x => x.Connection2).ThenBy(x => x.Connection1)` and not the code you wrote. Secondly, you can not have it sorted by Connection2 and have the brown fileds grouped at the same time. And thirdly, you can not even have it grouped by Connection2 and also Connection1 at the same time, generally. You should define more precisely what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Group By the values according to `Label, Connection1, Connection2` then sort by these 3 fields and finally the desired output is generated.

```
var wires = RedConductorWires
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.Label,a.Connection2, a.Connection1})
    .Join(RedConductorWires,
       left=>new { left.Key.Label,left.Key.Connection1,left.Key.Connection2},
       right => new { right.Label, right.Connection1, right.Connection2 },
       (left,right)=>new {left=left.Key,right = right })
    .OrderBy(x => x.left.Label)
    .ThenBy(x => x.left.Connection2)
    .ThenBy(x => x.left.Connection1)
    .ToList();


foreach(var item in wires)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.left.Label + "----" + item.left.Connection1 + "-----" + item.left.Connection2);
}
```

or

```
 var wires = RedConductorWires
            .OrderBy(x => x.Label)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Connection2, x.Connection1 })
            .Select(grp => grp.ToList()).SelectMany(i => i)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Connection2)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Connection1)
            .ToList();

foreach(var item in wires)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Label + "----" + item.Connection1 + "-----" + item.Connection2);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not give the correct output at all. See my edit though, I got the grouping to work now I just need to have the overall groups sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this lines

```
A - B
C - B
C - D
A - D
```

you can reorder the lines any way you like and either you would have first column grouped or second column grouped. But you can never have both at the same time

Comment: See my edit. I got the grouping portion of it to work, I just need to sort the overall groups now.

Comment: Your new code is equivalent to `RedConductorWires.OrderBy(x => x.Label).ToList()` as no group would have more that one item.

Answer (score 0):

I got the grouping to work correctly with the following query. I decided to keep it sorted on label initially.

```
var wires = RedConductorWires
        .OrderBy(x => x.Label)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Connection2, x.Connection1 })
        .Select(grp => grp.ToList()).SelectMany(i => i).ToList();
```